# Latex software and guidelines

Tags: texmaker

I need to write a document with Latex and I installed TexMaker. Does anyone suggest any easier tool? And a good documentation since I am finding loads but I need to learn it as quickly as possible.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question will provoke opinion-based answers and is in general to broad.

Comment: Possible dupe of either http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides

Comment: [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/)

Comment: There aren't any! But we have to write our assignments with it...what a waste of time

Comment: @user3599420: LaTeX is never,never,never a waste of time! It's a good way to procrastinate, however :D

Comment: No :( I am reading about texmaker I hope I will figure it out :)